# UIButtonTypeCustom no longer works after the addition of an image

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I have a button with an image inside, when I press the button I want to get a popup. When the button was empty, without image inside, everything worked, I have now added the image and the button no longer works. Button corresponds to a IBAction and is connected to the XIB via an IBOutlet. What can I do?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {      
      //.....
      self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

        self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 502, 73, 33);
       [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_legenda.png"] 
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

     }else{

       self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(330, 917, 182, 68);
       [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_legenda.png"] 
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       self.myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
     }


 [self.view addSubview:self.myButton]; 
 /*The problem arose in this line, without addSubview the image  you could not see 
  but the button worked, added addSuview the image you see but the button does not 
  work anymore*/

  NSLog(@"The button is %@", self.myButton);

 /*The button is <UIButton: 0x80f1e90; frame = (330 917; 182 68); opaque = NO; 
  layer = <CALayer: 0x80f1210>>*/

     //.......

 }

 -(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender{
      //This method initially worked
 }
```

Comment: so myButton is an IBOutlet and you've connected it to a UIButton in interface builder? Why are you initialising it again here? `self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is already defined in the XIB your code is creating another distinct button without any event (IBAction) attached.

You can change your code to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{      
  //.....

 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 502, 73, 33);
   [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_legenda.png"] 
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

 }else{

   self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(330, 917, 182, 68);
   [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_legenda.png"] 
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   self.myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
 }

}
```

Other option is to have two XIB. One for iPad and other for iPhone.